# Is there any method to store API data in context API?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I want to fetch API data and store it in the context API and use it in other components. The problem is that whenever the page load initially it gives the error of

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
```

This is maybe due to the fact the API is fetching data afterward and the component is rendering first.
Here is my Context code:

```
 export const CrossRatesProvider = (props) => {
        const [crossRates, setCrossRates] = useState([])
    
        useEffect(() =>{
            async function fetchaud()
        { 
             await fetch('https://freecurrencyapi.net/api/v2/latest?apikey=6cfea260-497f-11ec-94b3-adf08d2418fe&base_currency=AUD')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            setCrossRates(data);
            console.log(data)
        })
    }
        fetchaud();
         },[])
        const value = {
            crates: [crossRates, setCrossRates]
        }
    
        return (
            <CrossRatesContext.Provider value={value}>
            {props.children}
        </CrossRatesContext.Provider>
            
        )
    }
```

And this is the component where i am using the context data:

```
export default function XnaToCountry() {
  const value = useContext(CrossRatesContext);
 const [cRates] = value.crates;
if ( !cRates.length) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <div>
       <Table responsive style={{fontSize:"small"}}>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>{(0.0119063760/cRates.data.AUD).toFixed(9)}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </Table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Is `XnaToCountry` wrapped in `CrossRatesProvider` in your application?

Comment: Yes it is wrapped

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Working solution

Context

```
import { useEffect, useState, createContext } from "react";

export const CrossRatesContext = createContext();

export const CrossRatesProvider = (props) => {
  const [crossRates, setCrossRates] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchaud() {
      await fetch(
        "https://freecurrencyapi.net/api/v2/latest?apikey=6cfea260-497f-11ec-94b3-adf08d2418fe&base_currency=AUD"
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
          setCrossRates(res.data);
        });
    }
    fetchaud();
  }, []);
  const value = {
    crates: [crossRates, setCrossRates]
  };

  return (
    <CrossRatesContext.Provider value={value}>
      {props.children}
    </CrossRatesContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

index.js

```
import { CrossRatesProvider } from "./context";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
    <CrossRatesProvider>
      <App />
    </CrossRatesProvider>,
  rootElement
);
```

Usage

```
export default function App() {
  const value = useContext(CrossRatesContext);
  const [cRates] = value.crates;
  console.log(cRates);
  return <div></div>;
}
```

Codesandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-lumiere-emx5k?file=/src/App.js

Comment: its still showing same error when you mention export default function App() {
  return <div>{cRates.data.AUD}</div>; in the last time of App() function .You can check this on codesandbox link.

Comment: @Beren As there is no property named 'data' in cRates, you will get an error if you use {cRates.data.AUD}. To access the AUD property of cRates, use {cRates.AUD}. Recheck the codesandbox link.